# CMake Visual Studio project dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake

My solution consists of a static library and a console application that uses it.
The solution is generated from CMakeLists.txt files (top-level file and two files for every project)
As I know project dependencies in CMake are managed by changing add_subdirectory() order.
However, it does not work for me

Providing the complete top-level file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(vtun CXX)
set(TARGET vtun)

set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT ${MY_BOOST_DIR}) 

find_package(Boost 1.55.0) 

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost libraries are required")
endif()

add_subdirectory(vtunlib)
add_subdirectory(console_client)
```

vtunlib project goes first, but anyway *.sln file does not include dependencies information and console_client is always built first

CMake 3.0, Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Project dependencies in CMake are  **not**  managed by changing `add_subdirectory()` order. You can specify target dependencies explicitly by [add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html) command:

> add_dependencies(< target> [< target-dependency>]...)
>
> Make a top-level < target> depend on other top-level targets to ensure that they build
>   before < target> does.

or some commands like [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) do it automatically:

> ...the build system to make sure the library being linked is
>   up-to-date before the target links.

So in case `console_client` links `vtunlib`, the command  `target_link_libraries(console_client vtunlib)` will handle build order automatically.